# Inner join sum SQL

Tags: sql, sum

I have been trying to do a SUM with inner join, however it shows each cell rather than adding them together and showing only in one cell, where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT SUM(trans) as 'Transactions',city as 'city' 
FROM account 
INNER JOIN branch 
ON branch.bID 
GROUP BY account.trans, branch.city;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query which will return the sum per city

```
SELECT SUM(trans) as 'Transactions', branch.city as 'city' 
FROM account 
INNER JOIN branch 
ON branch.bID = account.bID
GROUP BY branch.city;
```

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to close this question by accepting the answer if you think it helped and there by letting other's to benefit from the same.

Comment: Yes, I will it's telling me to wait a few minutes to accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `account.trans` in `Group by`. Since you added `account.trans, branch.city` in `group by` it will show `sum(trans)` per `trans` and `city`.

If you want `sum(trans)` per `city` then add `branch.city` alone in  `group by`

```
SELECT SUM(trans) as 'Transactions'
FROM account 
INNER JOIN branch 
ON branch.bID 
Group by branch.city;
```

Comment: Ah sorry I re-read my question, it was clear enough, each city should have its own total.

Comment: @JonSnow - Updated check now