# Monthly data Extraction for 2 different tables with a common field Using Joins

Tags: join, oracle11g

I have two different tables with a common field, now i want to extract monthly records from these tables in year wise.

for example table 1 have following records

```
date    items
01/20/2008  20
02/15/2008  10
01/23/2009  23
02/25/2009  12
03/15/2010  05
```

table 2

```
date       items
01/12/2008  02
02/09/2008  10
01/02/2009  03
02/10/2009  07
03/19/2010  12
```

And i need the output as follows

```
date      items
jan-2008   22
feb-2008   20 
jan-2009   26
feb-2009   19
jan-2010   17
```

With the help of joins

Comment: Is this mysql, or sql-server?  Also, can you tell us what version you are using so we can provide a more accurate answer?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You are more likely to get an answer if you have a go yourself.  Try writing the query.  If you can't get it working update the question to include the code you've tried and  what went wrong.  MySQL and SQL Server both have great documentation on JOINs.  If we knew which you were using we could include a link to the manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner join sum SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460601/inner-join-sum-sql)

Comment: Thanks for your answers and i am using oracle 11g

Comment: @KeerthilalHaridass your question is tagged and posted on SQL-SERVER  section. I will edit accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a `JOIN` to make this work.  This is a MSSQL implementation that should give you the results in your output.

```
SELECT [date], SUM(items) as items
FROM (
    SELECT LOWER(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [date]),3)) + '-' + CONVERT(VarChar(4), DatePart(yyyy, [date])) as [date], items
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LOWER(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [date]),3)) + '-' + CONVERT(VarChar(4), DatePart(yyyy, [date])), items
    FROM table2
) a
GROUP BY [date]
```

Comment: Great answer, but only works if he has the right version of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your version of SQL. Please run @@version and update your answer as to which version you are using. This is important because many date functions have been added to SQL SERVER 2012+. For instance, this problem can be easily resolved by using

MONTH(dateField), which returns, the month of the date. This will not work on 2008R2 or below. You can use DAY, MONTH and YEAR to get to use for an easy join.